# Installing Let's Encrypt Certificate on Postfix

Tags: ubuntu, dns, apache-http-server, postfix, letsencrypt

I would like to host a Postfix (mail) server (running Ubuntu). However, I need to get an SSL certificate (one that is recognised by most mail servers) installed onto it. I already have an SSL certificate installed on my Apache2 server (running Ubuntu), by Let's Encrypt, which I want to use for my mail server. I used the suggested one (certbot-auto), but it does not support a Postfix plugin, nor a DNS challenge. However, it says that there are other bot solutions I could use that support the DNS challenge.

What is the best course of action to install a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate onto a postfix server? (Note: both the apache2 and postfix servers will not be on the same machine, nor on the same IP address).